# Apache Shiro: Access WEB-INF from shiro.ini

Tags: java, web-applications, shiro

I am trying to use Shiro in order to authenticate the user of my web application (only one user).
The `shiro.ini` file in under `WEB-INF`. 
Since there is only one user and password, they are stored in a file named `user.properties`. I am using the `PropertiesRealm` in order to verify the credentials.

My question is how can I set the source path to the `WEB-INF/user.properties` file?

Since the `classpath` refers to `WEB-INF/classes` I can put this line in the `shiro.ini` file: `realm.resourcePath = classpath:/../user.properties` works, but it looks like an ugly workaround.

Is there a correct way to set this file as the `resourcePath` in Shiro and web app?

Comment: why not load property file from servletcontext -  using initparam?

Comment: Because the filter is filtering requests even before they reach the servlet so there is no ServletContext available. For example, now I only use plain HTML files (for the POC).